# Magento add to cart on search result page 2< creates endless loop

Tags: magento

On 1.7.0.2 Magento search result page creates endless loop if trying to add product to cart.
This only happens when you are browsing search result pages 2 or more.

Something to do with the URL?
"catalogsearch/result/index/?p=2&q=searchquery"

Any ideas?

Comment: Try it with demo store, entering - for the search term. This brings up 57 products and you can add them to the cart from page 2.

Answer (score 0):

i had a very similar issue where add to cart buttons worked everywhere except from the search page.

i managed to fix the issue by increasing the permissions on the js folder, not sure if this will fix your issue as well.